# How do I place a number of tables on one line?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` with a number of `<tables>` in it, how do I get these `<tables>` on one line?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>no-line-break</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #foo
            {
                width: 500px;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                overflow-x: auto;
            }
            .bar
            {
                float: left;
                width: 150px;
                margin: 5px;                
            }
            .bar th
            {
                background-color: #c0c0c0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="foo">
            <table class="bar">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Foo #1
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Bar #1
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="bar">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Foo #2
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Bar #1
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Bar #2
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Bar #3
                    </td>
                </tr>               
            </table>
                        <table class="bar">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Foo #3
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Bar #1
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="bar">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Foo #4
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Bar #1
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like they already should be...http://jsfiddle.net/T8pfZ/

Comment: @Dutchie432, the fourth table is wrapping and no scroll-bar is appearing.

Comment: Perhaps a traditional table layout may be what you're going for. http://jsfiddle.net/T8pfZ/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add another div inside `#foo` that is at least as wide as the sum of all tables with their margins and paddings so that they won´t wrap.

example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>no-line-break</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #foo
        {
            width: 500px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            overflow-x: auto;
        }
        #foo_inner
        {
            width: 650px;
        }
        .bar
        {
            float: left;
            width: 150px;
            margin: 5px;                
        }
        .bar th
        {
            background-color: #c0c0c0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="foo">
    <div id="foo_inner">
        <table class="bar">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Foo #1
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Bar #1
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="bar">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Foo #2
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Bar #1
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Bar #2
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Bar #3
                </td>
            </tr>               
        </table>
                    <table class="bar">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Foo #3
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Bar #1
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="bar">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Foo #4
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Bar #1
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a traditional table layout may be what you're going for.

http://jsfiddle.net/T8pfZ/2

Comment: The reason I can't use one table, is that I need to be able to sort the columns (via jQuery.sortable()).

Answer (score 1):

Make all of them `display:inline`. So, do this:

```
.bar
    {
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
        margin: 5px;                
        display: inline;
    }

#foo
    {
         width: 500px;
         border: 1px solid #000;
         overflow-x: auto;
         display: inline;
    }
```

Comment: If you use `display:inline` you cannot set the `width` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "display:inline;" to your Foo CSS block.  You may have to adjust your width.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you cant all the tables in the same line, so you need to put the display:inline in the #foo style.

```
#foo {
display:inline
}
```